# Download an uploaded file from the browser returns a white file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP .NET MVC application, and I am trying to download an uploaded file from the browser.
I actually use this code, that had no problem in other software.

```
public FileResult DownloadDocuments(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
    return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I see is that the pdf is returned white. I checked this:

1. the file in the file system is fine, if I open from the server or copy locally on my machine I can see it correctly
2. the file returned by the browser is different, I checked with hex editor and some bytes are not the same
3. the readAllBytes method return the correct byte array (i.e. the same bytes I can see in the original file)
4. on chrome I checked the har file, and the base64 of the file returned from asp net is correct (same bytes)
5. the final file has double the size (114kb -> 200kb)

It seems that for some reason that the file saved by the browser is messed up.
This happens with chrome/edge on any desktop PC with Windows.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try contenttype as application/pdf instead of oclet.

Comment: *"the final file has double the size (114kb -> 200kb)"* - do you have any middleware that adds something to the http response?

Comment: @AliK already tried, no effect.

Comment: @BagusTesa no, this happens even running on my machine.

Comment: i doubt its about mime type, given i always use `application/octet-stream` to force browser to download the file instead of opening it in browser. which is why i suspect a middleware in play (ever had one runaway error handling middleware adding stuff to the tail of a response). check the docs for asp mvc middleware (not the network middleware).